# What does "I'll be D.D. before I have done!" mean?

Tags: meaning, thomas-hardy, jude-the-obscure

I was reading *Jude the Obscure*, and I came across this line in Part First, VI:

> "...I must save money, and I will; and one of those colleges shall open its doors to me—shall welcome whom now it would spurn, if I wait twenty years for the welcome.
>   "I'll be D.D. before I have done!"

What does this mean? What is "D.D."?

Answer (score 7):

### Doctor of Divinity.

The context is Jude ambitiously planning out his future life as an academic clergyman in Christminster (Oxford). From the same passage:

> And then he continued to dream, and thought he might become even a bishop by leading a pure, energetic, wise, Christian life. [...]
>
> ["]Yes, Christminster shall be my Alma Mater; and I'll be her beloved son, in whom she shall be well pleased."

If he succeeds in getting into Christminster to study theology, he might well aspire to become a [D.D. or Doctor of Divinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Divinity).

See also the following passage from ["A Tragedy of Two Ambitions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Tragedy_of_Two_Ambitions), a short story [available here](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/58250/58250-h/58250-h.htm#IRONlink2H_4_0009) which bears some resemblances to *Jude the Obscure*  and [has been described](https://digitalcommons.colby.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2502&context=cq) as a "short story prelude" to the novel:

> ‘You’ll be a bishop, Joshua, before you have done!’
>
> ‘Ah!’ said the other bitterly, shaking his head. ‘Perhaps I might have been — I might have been! But where is my D.D. or LL.D.; and how be a bishop without that kind of appendage? Archbishop Tillotson was the son of a Sowerby clothier, but he was sent to Clare College. To hail Oxford or Cambridge as alma mater is not for me — for us! My God! when I think of what we should have been — what fair promise has been blighted by that cursed, worthless —’

Here again we see an ambitious youth referring to the D.D. and [LL.D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legum_Doctor) in his hope to become a successful academic at Oxford or Cambridge (here referred to by name rather than as part of Hardy's fictionalised Wessex).

Comment: Interesting paraphrase of Matthew 3:17/Mark 1:11/Luke 3:17 in that first quoted section. (Those three verses all effectively say "And a voice from heaven said, "This is my Son, whom I love; with him I am well pleased.", or thereabouts.)

Comment: @Ash Ooh, nice! That's a very subtle way (along with all the more in-your-face ways, of course) of showing how Jude veritably worships the idea of Christminster in everything he says and does.